# Print 2 functions with a space between

Tags: php

I'm trying to `echo` the returned value of 2 functions with a space in between, I've tried:

```
class="<?php echo strtolower($class).' '.is_array($arr) ? 'yes' : 'no'; ?>"
```

But the above doesn't output anything. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: That code should certainly be outputting `yes`, not "nothing".

Answer (score 4):

Your code says *"is the concatenation of `strtolower(…)`, `' '` and a boolean truthy?"* And since that's always so, it should always be outputting `yes`. This can best be avoided by not using concatenation but passing separate arguments to `echo`:

```
echo strtolower($class), ' ', is_array($arr) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

Now the last ternary expression is unrelated to the previous two.

Answer (score 3):

Just group up the ternary part.

`echo strtolower($class).' '.(is_array($arr) ? 'yes' : 'no');`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php echo strtolower('someText').' '.(is_array([]) ? 'yes' : 'no'); ?>
```

**result:** sometext yes

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
class="<?php echo strtolower($class); ?> <?php is_array($arr) ? echo 'yes' : echo 'no'; ?>"
```

You print out the result of a function (which is TRUE or FALSE). In this way you output a String Yes or No.

Comment: No need to write echo two times. Read about DRY principle.

Comment: I agree with the DRY principle and your comment that it is not needed. I do however just think it is more readable/maintainable afterwards (when you have less skilled/experienced people in your team).

Comment: Well less code is always more maintainable, and in this situation readability is not an issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to put

```
class="<?php echo strtolower($class).' '.(is_array($arr) ? 'yes' : 'no'); ?>"
```

Note the "()" around is_array